# Need help in building regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

What is the Regular expression for

```
OD
-0D

-123D

-145Y

234w

and not +234D or -678m etc.
```

I do have

```
string EXP_REGEX_VALID_LITERAL = @"[0-9]*[d|D|w|W|m|M|q|Q|y|Y]";
Regex regex = new Regex(EXP_REGEX_VALID_LITERAL);
return regex.IsMatch(inputString);
```

but it is failing for `"/0345d"`

**Validation Rules:**

the expression is a alphanumeric one(where the alphabets are optional) where the alphabets can be only d|D|w|W|m|M|q|Q|y|Y and can appear only after the numerals. Also if any character can come before any numerals that can only be a minus.so -123 is valid or -123d or 123d or 123w are valid. but not 23dw or +12d etc.

Thanks

Comment: Your regex validate the strings with 0 or more integers then 1 character. but I can't understand what you want.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please reformat it to list several examples of what you do what to match and several examples of what you dont want to match. The "and not +234D or -678m etc." doesn't make sense to me, neither does "but it is failing for "/0345d""

Comment: the expression is a alphanumeric one where the alphabets can be only d|D|w|W|m|M|q|Q|y|Y and can appear only after the numerals. Also if any character can come before any numerals that can only be a minus.so -123 is valid or -123d or 123d or 123w are valid. but not 23dw or +12d etc.

Comment: of course it will fail for something starting with a slash. Did you mean a leading minus? in which case you need [\-]? at the start. Also, you probably want [0-9]+ rather than [0-9]* otherwise you will accept strings with no digits at all.

Comment: but - is optional how to make [\-] as optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, may be this will work:

```
/^-?\d+[dwmqy]$/i
```

c# syntax (not quite sure):

```
Regex.Match("/0123d", "^-?\d+[dwmqy]$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Where:

```
^   begining of the string
-?  optionnal -
\d+ one or more digits
[dwmqy]  one of these char
$   end of the string

i   case insensitive
```

Comment: i tested with this case "0345d"

Comment: +1 : sounds good to me. Try without ^ and $ maybe ? Or because of the \i that I don't use, since I use the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase parameter.

Comment: @M42, your regex is correct, but C# does not take delimiters and (optional) flags after it: which may be the cause of priyanka.sarkar_2's problems.

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar_2, try: `@"^(?i)-?\d+[dwmqy]$"`

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar_2 - you can probably do better than "does not work". Can you post more examples in your question? Also, .Net does not support the `/.../` notation, or the flags. Remember to remove them.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Yes, I don't know c# syntax.

Comment: @kobi, huh, what? :) But it's still a bit unclear to me what the OP really wants. S/He seems to be wanting to match `"/0345d"` as well, in which case the `^` anchor could (or should) be omitted. A well, who knows?